# How to reset slick slide position?

Tags: jquery, nested, carousel, slideshow, slick.js

I am making nested slick slider. and I want that a click on any first slider element hide first slider and show the second slider (which is created on child block of the first). The issue I am getting is that the slide begins outside my preview block (see images)

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBXLD.png (first slide)
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIJNG.png (second slide, on click on first slide element)
3. [image: slick-track div outside slide block]

Here is my code:

html:

```
<div class="slides-preview">
<button type="button" class="arrow-prev></button>
<div class="slide1">
   <div class="slide1-elm">
      <div class="header">Name slide 1 element 1</div>
      <div class="slide2">
         <span class="close">close</span>
         <div class="option"></div>
         <div class="option"></div>
         <div class="option"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="slide1-elm">
      <div class="header">Name slide 1 element 2</div>
      <div class="slide2">
         <span class="close">close</span>
         <div class="option"></div>
         <div class="option"></div>
         <div class="option"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="slide1-elm">
      <div class="header">Name slide 1 element 3</div>
      <div class="slide2">
         <span class="close">close</span>
         <div class="option"></div>
         <div class="option"></div>
         <div class="option"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="arrow-next></button>
</div>
```

css:

```
.slide2 { display: none; }
button  { position: absolute; top: 0; }
.arrow-prev { left: 0; }
.arrow-next { right: 0; }
.close { }
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function initCompSlide(){
        $('.slide1').not('.slick-initialized').slick({
            infinite: false,
            initialSlide: 0,
            slidesToShow: 4,
            slidesToScroll: 4,
            slickSetOption: true,
            prevArrow: $('button.arrow-prev'),
            nextArrow: $('button.arrow-next')
        });
    }

    function initOptSlide(elm){
        elm.not('.slick-initialized').slick({
            infinite: false,
            initialSlide: 0,
            slidesToShow: 4,
            slidesToScroll: 4,
            focusOnSelect: true,
            slickSetOption: true,
            prevArrow: $('button.arrow-prev'),
            nextArrow: $('button.arrow-next')
        });
    }

    initCompSlide();

    $(document).on('click', '.slide1-elm', function () {
        var optBlock = $(this).find('.slide2');
        initOptSlide(optBlock);
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.close', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('.slide2.slick-initialized').slick('unslick'); //notworking
        $('.slide2.slick-initialized').slick('setPosition'); //not working
    });

});
```

See here to check another way I am using to achieve what I need http://jsfiddle.net/fmo50w7n/3631/. 
But it does not work as wanted.
I want that all the red blocks to be positioned from the same point under the first element of slide1 (Name s1 elm 1 or Name s4 elm 1)

Answer (score 5):

Finally I used something like:

```
$('.slick-slider').slick('slickGoTo', 0);
```

And it works. but nested slick slider have several others issues. So I decided to change the HTML structure. But if I need nested slides necessary, I will re-check again how to make them work.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I am not sure if you have missed something in your code, but I added it to codepen and it doesn't work https://codepen.io/swarad07/pen/qwONBG. Perhaps you can change this codepen to correctly reflect the issue you are having and we can help.

Secondly, upon first reading the issue and seeing your code, creating a new slick slider from the markup which is inside the slide of 1st (already initialized) slick slider might have some unforeseen issues.

You could easily do the same thing by keeping markup separate. When slide of any 1st slider is clicked, you check the slide via the class it has, and you initialize the corresponding 2nd slick slider from the markup we have in DOM.

```
<markup for main slick slider>
  <slide 1>
  <slide 2>
  <slide 3>
</markup for main slick slider>

<chidlren of slide 1>
<chidlren of slide 2>
<chidlren of slide 3>
```

When I click on Slide 1, I create a slider for children of slide 1. Same for slide 2 and so on.

This way you get rid of nesting, the UX still is the same, and markup is also simpler to manipulate.

To reset already created sliders to 0, you can use `$('.slick-slider').slick('slickGoTo', 0);` or `$('.slick-slider').slick('refresh');`